# calling selenium python script from php exec does not run

Tags: php, python, selenium-webdriver

I am calling python script from php using exec function

```
$output = "";
$result = "";
exec("python /home/user/work/testwithphantomjs.py",$output,$result);

 var_dump($output);
 var_dump($result);
```

The script does not run when I import selenium webdriver in the python script but if I do not import selenium webdriver it works.

```
from selenium import webdriver

print "inside start 1"
```

Comment: What does "the script does not run" mean? Errors or ?

Comment: Script does not run through php , but runs from terminal only.

Comment: I hope this will help for sure https://stackoverflow.com/a/45370665/6008000 Thanks